# Django, filtrar valores de un objeto a partir de un array

Tags: python, django

Tengo una query similar a la siguiente:

```
Modelo.objects.all().values('nombre','fecha','ciudad')
```

Hay alguna forma de pasar los parametros del método **values()** en forma de array? Tal que:

```
valores = ['nombre','fecha','ciudad']
Modelo.objects.all().values(valores)
```

Para poder construir la query de una forma más dinámica dependiendo de los requerimientos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza un asterisco para desempacar los valores de una lista:

```
valores = ['nombre','fecha','ciudad']
Modelo.objects.all().values(*valores)
```